# Parsing large, possibly compressed, files in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip

I am trying to parse a large file, line by line, for relevant information.
I may be receiving either an uncompressed or gzipped file (I may have to edit for zip file at a later stage).

I am using the following code but I feel that, because I am not inside the `with` statement, I am not parsing the file line by line and am in fact loading the entire file `file_content` into memory.

```
if ".gz" in FILE_LIST['INPUT_FILE']:
    with gzip.open(FILE_LIST['INPUT_FILE']) as input_file:
        file_content = input_file.readlines()
else:
    with open(FILE_LIST['INPUT_FILE']) as input_file:
        file_content = input_file.readlines()

for line in file_content:
    # do stuff
```

Any suggestions for how I should handle this?
I would prefer not to unzip the file outside the code block, as this needs to be generic, and I would have to tidy up multiple files.

Comment: use `readline()` instead of `readlines()` to read the file line by line

Comment: I think the issue is more to do with the fact by the time I get to `for line in file_content:` I've already opened, read into memory and closed the file.
I could use `readline()` as is but I'd have to duplicate the code for both of the `if else:` branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readlines` reads the file fully. So it's a no-go for big files.

Doing 2 context blocks like you're doing and then using the `input_file` handle outside them doesn't work (operation on closed file).

To get best of both worlds, I would use a ternary conditional for the context block (which determines if `open` or `gzip.open` must be used), then iterate on the lines.

```
open_function = gzip.open if ".gz" in FILE_LIST['INPUT_FILE'] else open
with open_function(FILE_LIST['INPUT_FILE'],"r") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
```

note that I have added the "r" mode to make sure to work on text not on binary (`gzip.open` defaults to binary)

Alternative: `open_function` can be made generic so it doesn't depend on `FILE_LIST['INPUT_FILE']`:

```
open_function = lambda f: gzip.open(f,"r") if ".gz" in f else open(f)
```

once defined, you can reuse it at will

```
with open_function(FILE_LIST['INPUT_FILE']) as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
```

Comment: I'd separate that long unreadable `with` statement. First determine how you're gonna open the file, `fopen = gzip.open if ".gz" in FILE_LIST['INPUT_FILE'] else open`, then do the rest, `with fopen(FILE_LIST['INPUT_FILE']) as input_file: ...`

Comment: can't please everyone :) lambda version is better because it can be reused (I don't like copy/paste of `FILE_LIST['INPUT_FILE']`)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've implemented your code and it works like a charm, thank you for the help and the very detailed explanation!